# Rails 4 - Use default locale when none is explicetely declared in the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, rails-i18n

This is my routes file in Rails 4

```
root 'static_pages#root'
get '/:locale' => 'static_pages#root', as: 'locale_root'

scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|de/  do
    # Everything else.,,
end
```

This creates proper urls, like `http://localhost:3000/en/books` or `http://localhost:3000/de/books`.

But now I would like that if no locale has been given, for instance `http://localhost:3000/books` it would still show the default one (English).

At the moment all I get is a simple `"books" is not a valid locale`.

How can I do that?

**Other files**

*Application controller*

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :set_locale

    protected

        def set_locale
            I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
        end

        def default_url_options(options = {})
            { locale: I18n.locale }.merge options
        end
```

*config/application.rb*

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
config.i18n.fallbacks      = [:en]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You routes file looks correct, try this on you application_controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 before_filter :set_locale

 def set_locale
   I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
 end

 def default_url_options(options = {})
  { locale: I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale ? nil : I18n.locale  }
 end
end
```

Note the difference in default_url_options, when locale is the default one, it sets to nil.

**Edit:** Like Dbugger said, the `root` must be inside your `scope` in `routes.rb`

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|de/  do
  root 'static_pages#root'
end
```

Comment: Half success. `http://localhost:3000/books/1/` works fine, but with `http://localhost:3000/books/` gets an `"books" is not a valid locale`. The error jumps on `set_locale`

Comment: Weird, i hava a project with that config that works like a charm. Did you set the `default_locale` on `config/application.rb`? If it helps, you can take a look on my project https://github.com/tegon/game-translator

Comment: Got it! You have the `root` inside your `scope` in `routes.rb`. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Please edit and accept my answer, it may helper others with same problem

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
root 'static_pages#root'
get '/books', to: redirect('/en/books')
get '/:locale' => 'static_pages#root', as: 'locale_root'

scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|de/  do
    # Everything else.,,
end
```

Comment: Well... yes. That will work. But I was hoping for something more generic... that will work with ALL kind of URLs :P Your solution only works with 1 URL.